# Make Eclipse default to JUnit4 rather than JUnit5 when the class only contains JUnit4 annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, junit4, junit5

A recent upgrade of groovy which brought with it JUnit5 has resulting in Eclipse wanting to run every test under JUnit5. I can sort of work around this by going to run configurations and tell Eclipse to use JUnit4, however this gets tedious.

Is it possible to tell Eclipse to always use JUnit4 for a particular project, including new tests?

Comment: which build tool are you using? I assume that you can configure the dependency as what to use to run the test.

Comment: If you are only using JUnit 4, you should be able to add an **exclude** to your build configuration (e.g., Maven or Gradle) in order to remove the transitive dependency on JUnit 5 that Groovy brings in. Have you tried that?

Comment: That might be my only option but I would prefer not to. Maven is able to run the tests fine I assume under junit 4, I would have expected eclipse (not to work lol) but at least to have an option to default to junit 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a profile and activate it in Eclipse only.

Example (assuming your problem arose by having a dependency to `groovy-all`):

```xml
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>eclipse-groovy-no-junit5</id>
            <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>${groovy.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>${groovy.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-test-junit5</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Then go to

> `Project -> Properties -> Maven -> Active Maven Profiles`

and specify the profile name **`eclipse-groovy-no-junit5`**.

Remark: `groovy.groupId` is set to `org.codehaus.groovy` (it's a variable, because it will be replaced by `org.apache.groovy` in 4.x) and `groovy.version` is set to `3.0.8`.

If you want to be a bit more verbose, you can add...

```xml
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
```

...but it's the default anyway.